# UDF support removed from El Capitan?

Tags: diskutil

In previous versions of OS X, I used the [UDF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Disk_Format) format extensively.

I recently had to upgrade to El Capitan, and now none of my UDF drives are readable (Finder prompts me to intialize the disk).

Since previous versions of OS X supported it, and since UDF is a popular and widely used ISO standard format, I suspect that I'm just overlooking something. How do I get UDF support back?

UPDATE:
I have discovered that there is a [mount_udf](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/mount_udf.8.html) command. I tried it out and it caused a kernel panic. I can verify that the drives worked on my old Mac OS X system, and still do work on my Windows and Linux machines.

Comment: Try running fsck_udf on the disk. It's possible there's some corruption, which just happens to not be causing an issue on most operating systems. Either that or Apple borked something, which is always possible.

Comment: At this point, I don't trust Apple's UDF implementation to trust its fsck_udf tool. It seems unlikely that all 8 of my UDF drives would be corrupted in such a way that they work on all other OS's but OS X. Still, I will try an fsck on one of the drives from Linux and see if that avoids the Apple kernel panic.

Comment: Tried fsck on a drive, no improvement. I'm making a backup of one of the drives today, and I'll risk APple's UDF fsck tonight.

Comment: good luck! Smooth sailing.